# mvc client side validation with required attribute not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, client-side-validation

i am using bootstrap multiselect plugin

```
            <select class="btn btn-default  col-md-1" name="fw_dropdown" id="fw_dropdown" multiple="multiple" required="required">
            @foreach (var fw in Model.FWIndex)
            {
                <option value="@fw">@fw</option>
            }
        </select>
```

after I add the required attribute, the form is able to display a message that the field is not selected. **However, when I proceed to select the field, the message kept showing, which seems that the selected value cannot be received.** When I reload the project and select the required field, I am able to proceed with the submit query.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Adding a `[Required]` attribute to a collection property only means that it cannot be `null` (an empty collection with no elements passes). And using a repository pattern has nothing to do with it. You still have a model with properties, but in any case, if you editing data, thenyou should be using a view model - [What is ViewModel in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc).

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have edited the question. can you help take a look at it? Thanks!

Comment: That's not how to generate a `<select>` in MVC. Suggest you go to the MVC site and learn the basics (and you have not even shown the property your binding to or the attribute applied to it - and remove the `required="required"` - that's HTML-5 validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the `required` attribute only works for `select` class in IE when multiple selection is not enabled (I'm using bootstrap multiselect).

Instead I write a function in the submit button to achieve validation.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(event){
            $("form").submit(function(event){
                var fw=$("#fw_dropdown").val();
                if(fw=="" || fw==null){
                    alert("Please select FW!");
                    //prevent form submission
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                //allow form submission only when if is not true
            });
        })
</script>
```

To generate the form in the web application I used the html helper.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Query", "Actuals"))
```

That's why `"form"` is used instead of form id